# Auto Refresh Charts on Google Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I have a form where the answers go to a spreadsheet, which generates a chart based on the answers. These charts are inserted in a slide, which I intend to send by email automatically. The problem is that when the spreadsheet chart is updated with new information, the slide chart (which is linked) does not update automatically, I need to click on it to update it. I have a script that updates the charts, however, my problem is with the triggers. I put a trigger that fires whenever a new response is submitted, but the trigger fires too quickly, the graph with the new information is still being generated when it updates, so I need to create a delay. I thought about the "after ( durationMilliseconds) ", but I don't know where to insert it in my code.  It is worth mentioning that the form, spreadsheet, slides, and the scripts, are being made by Google platforms. This is my code:

```
function setUpTrigger() {
var form = FormApp.openById('###');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('refreshCharts')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

function refreshCharts(){
    var gotSlides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
    for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.length; i++) {
        var slide = gotSlides[i];
        var sheetsCharts = slide.getSheetsCharts();

        for (var k = 0; k < sheetsCharts.length; k++) {
            var shChart = sheetsCharts[k];
            shChart.refresh();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me, `refresh` is unknown function. Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a delay in the `refreshCharts()` function in the first line of the function.

```
  Utilities.sleep(5000); // 5 second delay
```

[Link to docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)